# nodejs resolving dependency using npm + package.json

Tags: node.js, npm

I have structured my project like

> ```
>  /
>     index.js
>     package.json
>     node_modules
>     |_Service_A
>       |__main.js
>       |__package.json
>     |_Service_B
>       |__main.js
>       |__package.json
> ```

When I do `npm install` on my project root directory the dependencies mentioned in /package.json is resolved but not the ones in node_modules/Service_A/package.json or node_modules/Service_B/package.json. How can I make npm to resolve dependencies across different folders?

Service_A and Service_B are local modules I had preloaded inside node_modules [they have dependencies]. I know I can take their dependency and put them in the top level json only, but what if they have dependency over same module but different versions. Ex: Service_A requires jquery 1.6 and Service_B jquery 1.7?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Service_A and Service_B are local modules i assume that are not defined in your top level package.json dependecies section. So npm don't know they even exists.

Consider developing your local modules under git repository, then you are able to define them in following way:

```
"dependencies": {
  "public": "git://github.com/user/repo.git#ref", 
  "private": "git+ssh://git@github.com:user/repo.git#ref"
}
```

Comment: I personally chose to go with this idea long way back after getting bored awaiting an answer for this question :) http://itsallabtamil.blogspot.in/2012/07/npm-package-manager-for-node-and.html So, I consider accepting your answer

Answer (score 2):

You could add something into into your package to call npm install on those package.json files . Something like below might do the trick.

```
"scripts": {
   "preinstall": "npm install Service_A/ && npm install Service_B/"
}
```